# non $p$ part of the class group and analogous results

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, iwasawa-theory

Washington had proven in 1978 that for $q$ a prime ($q \neq p$), if $q^{e_n}$ exactly divides the class number of $\mathbb{Q}_n$, ie the $n$-th layer in the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension, then $e_n$ is bounded independent of $n$. Are there analogous (partial) results for (dual of) Selmer groups?

Comment: I am only aware of the work of Jack Lamplugh. He has an article entitled "An analogue of the Washington-Sinnott theorem for elliptic curves with complex multiplication I." From the list of articles on mathscinet pointing at the one by Washington, I would guess that this is all there is.